# Paypal users can't login when Security Key is active

Tags: paypal

I'm having an issue on my website where Paypal users can't login to the lightbox when they have enabled SMS authentication through their mobile phone.  Is there a quick setting in my Paypal merchant account, or a specific API that I must use?  I've searched Google for a couple hours and all I can seem to find is tons of articles about breaching two factor.  Please help!

Comment: This may be a real PayPal limitation; at times PayPal has left certain login forms without support for 2FA. I would call them directly and try to get a straight answer on whether your specific payment flow supports 2FA login or not. This will require you to identify to them which specific product you are integrating (e.g. Express Checkout Digital Goods or Adaptive or RESTful or Braintree...).

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this same exact issue. I replicated some customer complaints with turning on Security on my personal account and trying to pay with PayPal.

When Security Key is on, I get the error: "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

There are two ways to prevent this from happening:

1. Be logged into PayPal already in a separate window, having gone through SMS authentication.
2. Turning off Security Key.

I've submitted the issue to PayPal.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? I too am facing the same issue.